# Filtering output in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm new with Hadoop and playing around with the `WordCount` example.

I ran into an issue that is confusing me. If I take word count from a text file and I want to, for example, filter it in a such way that only words longer than 5 letters are in the output, do I have to run 2 jobs to do this?

The first job to do the word count and second job to filter the words shorter than 5 letters?

Or can I just write logic into reducer that does not write the word into the result file if there are less then 5 occurrences? Would this result an invalid output if there are multiple instances of the reducer running?

Answer (score 0):

> **Simple answer is you don't need to jobs.**

You can achieve this with a **single job**. The logic you have described into the last of the problem is absolutely correct.

In the MapReduce framework, all the data (values) related to a single keys always passed to the same `Reducer`. So even if multiple reducers are running for your job will not affect the output.

**PS:**

> only words longer than 5 letters are in the output

This is from second paragraph of your problem. I am assuming that you mean 5 occurrence of a word not the length of the word.

But you want only words with more than 5 length, that you can filter in `Mapper` itself. So there will be less data for `sort-shuffle` phase (data sorting and transfer over network) and less data process for `Reducer`.

Answer (score 0):

One MapReduce job should be enough.

The best-practices say that you should **filter** and **project** data in the mapper if it is possible.

In you case, your filter condition only depends on the input data (characters in the input word), then you could filter the input in the mapper side and only send to the reducer words with more than 5 letters. Improving the performance of your job. It doesn't make sense send the data to the reducer to drop it. Although it should work too.